# Error implementing bbcode.py with flask app

Tags: python, flask, bbcode

Am using this module =>https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbcode/1.0.21 and <del>it doesn't seem to work.</del>The module couldn't parse the bbcodes in the template and it given an error that *text not defined* Ps: Any other bbcode parser for flask would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's problem with this? Can you explain more? "it doesn't seem to work" not enough for anyone to help you!

Comment: @RaminNietzsche i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Python code, you can define `bbcode` and convert string with them to HTML by `bbcode.render_html()`

### app.py:

---

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

import bbcode

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<name>/')
def hello_world(name):
    bb_user = bbcode.render_html('[b]' + name + '[/b]')
    return render_template('index.html',
                           user=bb_user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And then you can use this in your html.

### index.html

---

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
welcome {{ user | safe }} !
</body>
```

The `safe` params, allow using HTML code in jinja.
You can read [The Flask Mega-Tutorial, Part II: Templates](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates).

Comment: Am a total newbie, can you please improve your answer to make it implementable with a jinja filter. Just like markdown.py

Comment: @Jayson_X I changed it

Comment: Worked, but the variable i want to be formated is from a database <pre>data=g.db.execute("select name,value,body from bangs where title=?",[title]).fetchall()</pre> How do i go from here. Cheers!

Comment: please read this tutorial: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database